# How to create custom Registration and Login API using Strapi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am using strapi to create APIs.
I want to implement my own Registration API and Login API.
I checked the documentation of strapi but i am not finding any custom API for this.

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Which kind of function or field do you want to implement into the custom registration?

Answer (score 15):

Same answer, but in more detail:

Strapi creates an Auth controller automatically for you and you can overwrite its behavior.

Copy the function(s) you need (e.g. `register`) from this file:

`node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js`

to:

`your_project_root/extensions/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js`

Now you can overwrite the behavior, e.g. pass a custom field inside the registration process `{"myCustomField": "hello world"}` and log it to the console:

```js
async register(ctx) {
  ...
  ...
  // log the custom field
  console.log(params.myCustomField)

  // do something with it, e.g. check whether the value already exists
  // in another content type
  const itExists = await strapi.query('some-content-type').findOne({
    fieldName: params.myCustomField
  });
  if (!itExists) {
    return ctx.badRequest(...)
  } else {
    console.log('check success')
  }
}
```

Comment: The new directory should also be `users-permissions` instead of `user-permissions`.

Comment: In Strapi V4 `node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/controllers/Auth.js`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, strapi creates an Auth controller to handle these requests. You can just change them to fit in your need.

The path to the controller is:

`plugins/users-permissions/controllers/Auth.js`

Comment: This is the correct approach. Mind that all default plugins are moved to **node_modules** after *Strapi 3.0.0-beta*, so take a look into: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/migration-guide/migration-guide-alpha.26-to-beta.html#migrating-plugins  for modifying stock plugins.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create custom users-permissons apis on server side you have to create

> src/extensions/users-permissions/strapi-server.js

and in that file can write or override existing user-permissions plugin apis

here is the example for users/me

```html
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  const getController = name => {
    return strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].controller(name);
  };

  // Create the new controller
  plugin.controllers.user.me = async (ctx) => {
    const user = ctx.state.user;

    // User has to be logged in to update themselves
    if (!user) {
      return ctx.unauthorized();
    }
      console.log('calling about meeeeeeeeeee------')
      return;
 
  };

  // Add the custom route
  plugin.routes['content-api'].routes.unshift({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users/me',
    handler: 'user.me',
    config: {
        prefix: '',
    }
  });

  return plugin;
};
```